# Remove the beginning characters in a cell while maintaining the formula for removing the trailing characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the data formats that I'm working with

```
Original        Expected
300342          300342
3003743         3003743
3000483a        3000483
3004375v2       3004375
3004375v3       3004375
3124275IE08     3124275
3124275IE11     3124275
321251b         321251
KBZ_KB3018238   3018238
```

The following code corrects for the trailing characters but not the beginning KBZ_KB.  I am unsure how to update the code so that if the beginning characters are found they are removed as well.

```
=IFERROR(--LEFT(A2,MIN(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2)))))-1),A2)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode. If done correctly then excel will put {} around the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, it would be easiest to break it out into separate cells with helper columns.  You can hide these helper columns or Cut them to a hidden worksheet if preferred so that you only have Original and Output:

[image]

In cell B2 and copied down:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),),0)
```

In cell C2 and copied down:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT(B2&":"&LEN(A2)+1)),1)),),0)-1+B2-1
```

In cell D2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(--MID(A2,B2,C2),A2)
```

Putting the entire formula in a single cell will result in a very large mess that's difficult to interpret or update.  However, if you absolutely must have it all in a single formula:

```
=IFERROR(--MID(A2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),),0),MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),),0)&":"&LEN(A2)+1)),1)),),0)-1+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),),0)-1),A2)
```

Note that none of these are array formulas, they do not require confirmation with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Breaking it all out made it much easier to read and the fact that it is not an array formula made it even easier.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,--MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),ROW($A$1:$A$100)))
```

Change A1 (at two places) in formula to match your data but don't change A1 in ROW($A$1:$A$100)

Comment: This is a very clever solution, +1

Answer (score 0):

you can also adapt your array formula like this to achieve the desired result:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,1))),MID(A2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A2))),1)),0),LEN(A2)-MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A2))),1)),0)),IFERROR(MID(A2,1,-1+MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A2))),1)),0)),A2))
```

Please note that this is an array formula and that you have to confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of only pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key.
[image: array formula]

Answer (score 0):

Check out if this array formula works with your data:

```
=MID(A2,IFERROR(MIN(SEARCH(ROW($A$1:$A$9),A2)),1),MIN(IFERROR(ROW($A$1:$A$40)*100+MID(MID(A2,IFERROR(MIN(SEARCH(ROW($A$1:$A$9),A2)),1),LEN(A2)),ROW($A$1:$A$40),1),ROW($A$1:$A$40)))-1)
```